Error while calling AWS kendra API from AEM servlet : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.KendraClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.AttributeFilter;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.DocumentAttribute;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.DocumentAttributeValue;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.QueryRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.QueryResponse;




@Component(service = {Servlet.class},
property = {
    "sling.servlet.paths=/bin/cookieservlet"
    }
)

public class CookieServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet{

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CookieServlet.class);

    
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
       
        

        String accessKey = "AKIAYHKHKJHUMDP4B";
        String secretKey = "V9wWb3Hz6oGIUHUKHKDdfyiushdPsOOqzsbdYf/Zxse";
        String indexId = "6cc7a433-d9ea-4c68-9b06-76646d6a2529";

        AwsCredentials awsCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);

        KendraClient kendraClient = KendraClient.builder()
                                            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                                            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials))
                                            .build();



                                            
      
        QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest.builder()
                                        .queryText(searchWord)
                                        .indexId(indexId)
                                        .build();
       QueryResponse queryResult = kendraClient.query(queryRequest);
       if(queryRequest!=null){
        log.info("Query executed successfully",queryRequest);
       }

       response.getWriter().write(queryResult.toString());
       response.sendRedirect(targetPageUrl);

   }
}






 



I am trying to make a connection to aws kendra and used the following lines of code.
I am getting the following error :
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. (Service: Kendra, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 06ce1fc5-e040-4939-9a85-3e9b245f7a2e)

The issue resolved after creating new Access key.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
